# How to override product view page in magento 2

Tags: product, magento2, overrides

I want to override product view page and add my custom code over that.

So please help me on how can I override template of product view page.

Thank you.

Comment: Have many methods to custom template of product view page. May you show detail which you want to custom on the page.

Answer (score 7):

@Dmync In order to accomplish this the basic answer is "it depends." The first question that would need to be answered is "What do you want to override?" This question is too broad.

If you're trying to override some template(s) that are in place by default for product view then you can need to track down the templates you want to override. You can do so by either of the following:

1. Follow directions here: [enable template hints](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/debug-theme.html)
2. Go to `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` and track down all the template files that are explicitly assigned here, as well as all other templates included via `<update>` layout instruction [update docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html)

Once you know which templates you want to update, then you can follow the general ideas within this [page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-walkthrough.html) to create the correct module structure. Basically if you're creating a module to perform these actions then you'll need a structure like:

`app/code/<Vendor>/<module>/view/frontend/Magento_Catalog/templates` and then you'd continue to refer to the structure of `Magento_Catalog` for it's folder hierarchy...and you'd add that into your module...so

If you're wanting to override `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml` then you'd create `app/code/<Vendor>/<Module>/view/frontend/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/form.phtml`. Then you could do your customizations there..again, refer to the templates customization doc I linked.

If you're trying to do this via a theme. Using the above example....you'd create `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Catalog/product/view/form.phtml` and perform whatever customizations you'd like in that template.

So which ever way you go about it, either creating a custom module or a custom design theme, and if you're simply modifying the template content, you're going to need to recreate the target module (in this case Magento_Catalog) in your own custom module/theme (using the correct directory hierarchies...as it's slightly different between module/theme).

If you're interested in modifying css then look here for info on [overriding css](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html).

If you need to modify some of the page's layout xml files to rearrange elements, remove elements, add elements, etc...look [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html) to get started.

As you can see, there's a lot that can take place in simply "Overriding product view page."

Comment: Correct structure isn't needed when overriding via module. You need to set template in xml. For instance, https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/169589/46716

Answer (score 2):

If you want only override template file of product view page,
You need to set template inside your custom theme file from `vendor/module-catalog`,

```
Magento2/app/design/frontend/{{Packagename}}/{{themename}}/Magento_Catalog/templates/
```

After insert template in above path and you can change your custom code related to view file.

Thanks.

Comment: how to override from admin side? I need to override the product view of admin

Answer (score 0):

First, create Module
put etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

Then create a registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendor_Module', __DIR__);
```

Find the xml file and native template files you have to override. Incase of PDP you can override the following files

view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
      <referenceBlock name="product.info">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/view/form.phtml</argument>
        </action>
     </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

change the block names and paths for different templates.

create the form.phtml and insert your modifications there.
view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> write your code here</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

usually we copy and paste the original template file and change it as we want.