# Can't override template file in Magento 2.1 module

Tags: product, magento-2.1, layout, template, addtocart

I'm trying to override Magento's built-in `addtocart.phtml` file, but nothing I try seems to be working.

I Have a module named `QuantityDropdown` under the `Rethink` namespace. As far as I can see it's installed properly as it displays in the list when I run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and my `Setup/InstallSchema.php` file properly creates a database table.

I've copied the original file from:

**/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml**

...to my local version at:

**/app/code/Rethink/QuantityDropdown/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml**

I then created a new XML file to point to my module's phtml file:

**/app/code/Rethink/QuantityDropdown/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

which contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Rethink_QuantityDropdown::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
         </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I also updated my module file at `/app/code/Rethink/QuantityDropdown/etc/module.xml` file to include Magento_Catalog in the sequence:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Rethink_QuantityDropdown" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

I've also tried several different XML methods in my `catalog_product_view.xml` but nothing seems to be working.

Are there any other changes I should be making in the admin panel or are changes just based on the XML files? I feel like I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use below code in your **catalog_category_view.xml** file,
remove cache and check,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Rethink_QuantityDropdown::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>    
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Rethink_QuantityDropdown::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>       
    </body>
</page>
```