# how to load phtml template after price in product details page magento 2 custom theme?

Tags: magento2

> Actually i want to load phtml templates after price in product details page
>   magento 2 custom theme

Answer (score 0):

You can't load one template into another, but all you can do is, to call block files instead. Answer to your question and best practices is that, you can override product view template with new template file, in this new file you can add your custom code as well as per requirement.

[How to override product view page in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101120/how-to-override-product-view-page-in-magento-2)

Have a look at this link.
hope it helps.